# How to increase row size in css grid?

Tags: css-grid

[Screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdxU8.png)

how can I increase the size of row in CSS grid? the row takes the the size according to the content in it, despite assigning it a particular size.

Comment: Can i see your code,which is already you tried

Comment: You can do like this in your CSS class  **grid-template-rows: 100px 300px;** Specify height and width what ever you want instead of 100px and 300px